# How to Specify Spyder as IDE for Google App engine Launcher?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, spyder, anaconda

I'm having problems specify Spyder as the IDE to use for Google App Engine Launcher. The launcher can accurately find Sublimetext exe but to specify the path for Spyder is a problem. I prefer spydr because I find Anaconda more complete than SublimeText.

If it helps at all, I use Spyder bundled with the Anaconda distribution. I know I can launch spyder by calling Spyder.bat from cmd but if I want another program to launch Spyder what path do I specify?

Comment: And where is it located in Anaconda folder? :P You need to either call it via its full path or add it to system variables so whatever directory you launch it from OS will now where the `Spyder.bat` is located. Besides you can download stand-alone Spyder, don't need Anaconda for that. But I do agree that it's a nice IDE

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I've tried the path of the batch file located in C:\Anaconda\Scripts\spyder.bat. It runs the batch file alright but the editor doesn't launch.
Yes, anaconda is not needed for GAE launcher but I use it for other programming work and I prefer it because it comes with Spyder and ipython among other useful tools.

Comment: I use `python(x,y)` but that;s a matter of preference. Anyway when you specify the launcher (not familiar with that at all) just type in `C:\Anaconda\Scripts\Spyder.bat`. It should work.